# Recieved BSOD after restart

Tags: windows-8, bsod

When i start my laptop i get this error "DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION" i really donyt know what is the issue... can some one help....

---

### Dump File

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17336 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [I:\121115-55411-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9200 MP (2 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 9200.16384.amd64fre.win8_rtm.120725-1247
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff803`2dc71000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff803`2df3ba60
Debug session time: Fri Dec 11 08:20:59.413 2015 (UTC + 5:30)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:51.132
Loading Kernel Symbols
.

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

..............................................................
................................................................
...............
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.....
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 133, {1, 784, 0, 0}

Probably caused by : i8042prt.sys ( i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService+96 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. The offending component can usually be
    identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000784, The watchdog period.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  smss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17336 (debuggers(dbg).150226-1500) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8032de45637 to fffff8032dcec040

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`05463a88 fffff803`2de45637 : 00000000`00000133 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000784 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`05463a90 fffff803`2dd16f11 : 00000000`00000ccc fffff880`0099b180 fffff880`05463bf0 fffff780`00000320 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x13c00
fffff880`05463b10 fffff803`2dc27e84 : ffffffff`ffd0b270 fffff803`2dc5190b ffffffff`ffd0b270 fffff803`2dc5190b : nt!KeUpdateRunTime+0x51
fffff880`05463b40 fffff803`2dce5bca : ffffffff`ffd01000 ffffffdb`a826b350 fffff803`2dc519a0 ffffffdb`aaa83977 : hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0x50
fffff880`05463b70 fffff803`2dc30ba2 : fffff803`2dc230d0 098809a8`09a809c8 fffff880`05463d80 0a000a1c`0a1c0a38 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x1aa
fffff880`05463d08 fffff803`2dc230d0 : 098809a8`09a809c8 fffff880`05463d80 0a000a1c`0a1c0a38 fffff880`05463d90 : hal!HalpTscQueryCounter+0x2
fffff880`05463d10 fffff880`06bcd792 : fffffa80`04a9e190 fffffa80`04a9e190 fffff880`05463ea0 fffff880`02c7c480 : hal!HalpTimerStallExecutionProcessor+0x131
fffff880`05463da0 fffff803`2dce5106 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`04a9e040 00000000`0000e100 fffffa80`04a9e514 : i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService+0x96
fffff880`05463e20 fffff803`2ddad4c1 : fffff880`02c7cb40 fffff803`2dce51a3 00000000`0000e138 fffffa80`04f75b01 : nt!KiInterruptDispatch+0x1d6
fffff880`05463fb0 fffff803`2dce51a3 : 00000000`0000e138 fffffa80`04f75b01 fffff880`05464040 fffff803`00000000 : nt!KiDpcInterruptBypass+0x11
fffff880`05463fc0 ffffffff`ff8456b7 : 00000000`000000fc 00000000`00000006 fffffa80`055d69a0 ffffffff`ff643018 : nt!KiInterruptDispatch+0x273
fffff880`05464158 00000000`000000fc : 00000000`00000006 fffffa80`055d69a0 ffffffff`ff643018 ffffffff`ff839e40 : 0xffffffff`ff8456b7
fffff880`05464160 00000000`00000006 : fffffa80`055d69a0 ffffffff`ff643018 ffffffff`ff839e40 00000000`00008ff6 : 0xfc
fffff880`05464168 fffffa80`055d69a0 : ffffffff`ff643018 ffffffff`ff839e40 00000000`00008ff6 00000001`00000000 : 0x6
fffff880`05464170 ffffffff`ff643018 : ffffffff`ff839e40 00000000`00008ff6 00000001`00000000 00000028`00000000 : 0xfffffa80`055d69a0
fffff880`05464178 ffffffff`ff839e40 : 00000000`00008ff6 00000001`00000000 00000028`00000000 00000000`00000028 : 0xffffffff`ff643018
fffff880`05464180 00000000`00008ff6 : 00000001`00000000 00000028`00000000 00000000`00000028 00000000`00000007 : 0xffffffff`ff839e40
fffff880`05464188 00000001`00000000 : 00000028`00000000 00000000`00000028 00000000`00000007 ffffffff`ff83c44c : 0x8ff6
fffff880`05464190 00000028`00000000 : 00000000`00000028 00000000`00000007 ffffffff`ff83c44c 00000000`0000e000 : 0x00000001`00000000
fffff880`05464198 00000000`00000028 : 00000000`00000007 ffffffff`ff83c44c 00000000`0000e000 ffffffff`ff652e18 : 0x00000028`00000000
fffff880`054641a0 00000000`00000007 : ffffffff`ff83c44c 00000000`0000e000 ffffffff`ff652e18 fffff880`05464360 : 0x28
fffff880`054641a8 ffffffff`ff83c44c : 00000000`0000e000 ffffffff`ff652e18 fffff880`05464360 fffff880`05464220 : 0x7
fffff880`054641b0 00000000`0000e000 : ffffffff`ff652e18 fffff880`05464360 fffff880`05464220 fffffa80`055d69a0 : 0xffffffff`ff83c44c
fffff880`054641b8 ffffffff`ff652e18 : fffff880`05464360 fffff880`05464220 fffffa80`055d69a0 00000000`00000000 : 0xe000
fffff880`054641c0 fffff880`05464360 : fffff880`05464220 fffffa80`055d69a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xffffffff`ff652e18
fffff880`054641c8 fffff880`05464220 : fffffa80`055d69a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffff880`05464360
fffff880`054641d0 fffffa80`055d69a0 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffff880`05464220
fffff880`054641d8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffffa80`055d69a0


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService+96
fffff880`06bcd792 488b0da77a0000  mov     rcx,qword ptr [i8042prt!Globals (fffff880`06bd5240)]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  7

SYMBOL_NAME:  i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService+96

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: i8042prt

IMAGE_NAME:  i8042prt.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5010ab62

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.2.9200.16384

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  96

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService

BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x133_isr_i8042prt!i8042keyboardinterruptservice

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {117a9501-1900-b3a1-9f9f-c7b1c3cf783e}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. The offending component can usually be
    identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000784, The watchdog period.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  smss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17336 (debuggers(dbg).150226-1500) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8032de45637 to fffff8032dcec040

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`05463a88 fffff803`2de45637 : 00000000`00000133 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000784 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`05463a90 fffff803`2dd16f11 : 00000000`00000ccc fffff880`0099b180 fffff880`05463bf0 fffff780`00000320 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x13c00
fffff880`05463b10 fffff803`2dc27e84 : ffffffff`ffd0b270 fffff803`2dc5190b ffffffff`ffd0b270 fffff803`2dc5190b : nt!KeUpdateRunTime+0x51
fffff880`05463b40 fffff803`2dce5bca : ffffffff`ffd01000 ffffffdb`a826b350 fffff803`2dc519a0 ffffffdb`aaa83977 : hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0x50
fffff880`05463b70 fffff803`2dc30ba2 : fffff803`2dc230d0 098809a8`09a809c8 fffff880`05463d80 0a000a1c`0a1c0a38 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x1aa
fffff880`05463d08 fffff803`2dc230d0 : 098809a8`09a809c8 fffff880`05463d80 0a000a1c`0a1c0a38 fffff880`05463d90 : hal!HalpTscQueryCounter+0x2
fffff880`05463d10 fffff880`06bcd792 : fffffa80`04a9e190 fffffa80`04a9e190 fffff880`05463ea0 fffff880`02c7c480 : hal!HalpTimerStallExecutionProcessor+0x131
fffff880`05463da0 fffff803`2dce5106 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`04a9e040 00000000`0000e100 fffffa80`04a9e514 : i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService+0x96
fffff880`05463e20 fffff803`2ddad4c1 : fffff880`02c7cb40 fffff803`2dce51a3 00000000`0000e138 fffffa80`04f75b01 : nt!KiInterruptDispatch+0x1d6
fffff880`05463fb0 fffff803`2dce51a3 : 00000000`0000e138 fffffa80`04f75b01 fffff880`05464040 fffff803`00000000 : nt!KiDpcInterruptBypass+0x11
fffff880`05463fc0 ffffffff`ff8456b7 : 00000000`000000fc 00000000`00000006 fffffa80`055d69a0 ffffffff`ff643018 : nt!KiInterruptDispatch+0x273
fffff880`05464158 00000000`000000fc : 00000000`00000006 fffffa80`055d69a0 ffffffff`ff643018 ffffffff`ff839e40 : 0xffffffff`ff8456b7
fffff880`05464160 00000000`00000006 : fffffa80`055d69a0 ffffffff`ff643018 ffffffff`ff839e40 00000000`00008ff6 : 0xfc
fffff880`05464168 fffffa80`055d69a0 : ffffffff`ff643018 ffffffff`ff839e40 00000000`00008ff6 00000001`00000000 : 0x6
fffff880`05464170 ffffffff`ff643018 : ffffffff`ff839e40 00000000`00008ff6 00000001`00000000 00000028`00000000 : 0xfffffa80`055d69a0
fffff880`05464178 ffffffff`ff839e40 : 00000000`00008ff6 00000001`00000000 00000028`00000000 00000000`00000028 : 0xffffffff`ff643018
fffff880`05464180 00000000`00008ff6 : 00000001`00000000 00000028`00000000 00000000`00000028 00000000`00000007 : 0xffffffff`ff839e40
fffff880`05464188 00000001`00000000 : 00000028`00000000 00000000`00000028 00000000`00000007 ffffffff`ff83c44c : 0x8ff6
fffff880`05464190 00000028`00000000 : 00000000`00000028 00000000`00000007 ffffffff`ff83c44c 00000000`0000e000 : 0x00000001`00000000
fffff880`05464198 00000000`00000028 : 00000000`00000007 ffffffff`ff83c44c 00000000`0000e000 ffffffff`ff652e18 : 0x00000028`00000000
fffff880`054641a0 00000000`00000007 : ffffffff`ff83c44c 00000000`0000e000 ffffffff`ff652e18 fffff880`05464360 : 0x28
fffff880`054641a8 ffffffff`ff83c44c : 00000000`0000e000 ffffffff`ff652e18 fffff880`05464360 fffff880`05464220 : 0x7
fffff880`054641b0 00000000`0000e000 : ffffffff`ff652e18 fffff880`05464360 fffff880`05464220 fffffa80`055d69a0 : 0xffffffff`ff83c44c
fffff880`054641b8 ffffffff`ff652e18 : fffff880`05464360 fffff880`05464220 fffffa80`055d69a0 00000000`00000000 : 0xe000
fffff880`054641c0 fffff880`05464360 : fffff880`05464220 fffffa80`055d69a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xffffffff`ff652e18
fffff880`054641c8 fffff880`05464220 : fffffa80`055d69a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffff880`05464360
fffff880`054641d0 fffffa80`055d69a0 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffff880`05464220
fffff880`054641d8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffffa80`055d69a0


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService+96
fffff880`06bcd792 488b0da77a0000  mov     rcx,qword ptr [i8042prt!Globals (fffff880`06bd5240)]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  7

SYMBOL_NAME:  i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService+96

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: i8042prt

IMAGE_NAME:  i8042prt.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5010ab62

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.2.9200.16384

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  96

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService

BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_i8042prt!I8042KeyboardInterruptService

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x133_isr_i8042prt!i8042keyboardinterruptservice

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {117a9501-1900-b3a1-9f9f-c7b1c3cf783e}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have either a bad keyboard river or a broken keyboard (although the DPC watchdog error is usually associated with HDD driver errors).

Plug in a different keyboard as a first step, and fix/refresh/update your keyboard drivers as a second (remember to open an on-screen keyboard first, if you have to remove the driver before reinstalling).